# Most efficient way to select records consisting of one word

Tags: sql-server, sql

How do I write select query that selects records that contain only a single word in the column?

Take the following table as an example:

```
+--+---------------+
|id|name           |
+--+---------------+
|1 |chicken        |
+--+---------------+
|2 |cow            |
+--+---------------+
|3 |mixed          |
+--+---------------+
|4 |chicken bacon  |
+--+---------------+
|5 |chicken tenders|
+--+---------------+
|6 |cow bacon      |
+--+---------------+
|7 |cow tenders    |
+--+---------------+
|8 |mixed bacon    |
+--+---------------+
|9 |mixed tenders  |
+--+---------------+
```

In this case the answer would be `chicken`, `cow`, and `mixed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE name NOT LIKE '% %'
```

You can read more about `SELECT LIKE operand` on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp).

`%` sign also known as one of the `SQL Wildcards` and is bassically used for substituting for zero or more characters.

Read more about [SQL Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Comment: thx a lot this site will help me to improve my skills, apreciate it. and also thx for the answer

Comment: I'm glad to help, if it was answer to your question, please accept it is an answer so it could solve someone elses worries.

Comment: depending on data might also want to do LTRIM/RTRIM on the name in the query given.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the expression:

```
where name not like '% %'
```

will also say that `'name '`, `' name'` and `' name '` are all more than one word.  For this to work for these situations:

```
where ltrim(rtrim(name)) not like '% %'
```